# Can I set up a linux box with a managed switch as a sort of firewall between my security cameras and the rest of my home?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, vlan

I've got my home network, a netgear gs716tp (managed switch), a linux machine, and some security cameras.
I'm wanting to set things up so that my home network can see the linux machine, and the linux machine can see everything in the network, but the security cameras can only see the linux machine.

It looks to me like I should be able to set up 2 vlans, 1 including my home network & the linux machine.  The other including my cameras & the linux machine.  The issue I just thought of is that the cameras will then no longer have access to the dhcp server I use for most of my network.  I'm thinking I should be able to use the linux machine as a dhcp server for the cameras, but I don't want it being used by anything else on the network, I'd prefer to keep that on my normal router (although I suppose I could move it all over).

I guess my questions are:

1. Does this all make sense, or is there some other way I should be approaching this?
2. If it does make sense, I should be able to figure out how to do it, but any tips on how would be helpful.

Thanks much in advance :)
Kem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does make sense.

You would create a VLAN interface on the Linux box for the camera.

You can get a Linux DHCP server to bind to only this interface and solve your DHCP issue that way.  (Both ISC DHCPD and dnsmasq can do this)

Comment: I've got it working properly now, so thanks much :)